# How to select a file from a Folder in C#

Tags: c#

I want do select a file from a folder in my C# command line project.
For example, in C:\deployment\Test_Folder there are more than 10. I show the content of that folder with this code.

[image: Show Content of the folder]

I want to select, for example, the fifth file from that folder. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please add code instead of an image? The files is an array (or list) so you can access nr5 by the index or check for a certain filename etc.

Comment: It would also be useful to know the type of application - Console, WinForms, WPF. With the latter two you could use standard dialogs to select files.

Comment: okay sorry, it is a .cs -> Console. 
Code to Show the Folder Content : 

System.IO.DirectoryInfo ParentDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test_folder");

            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo f in ParentDirectory.GetFiles())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Datei: " + f.Name);
            }

Answer (score 1):

For a simple Command-line interface tool i'd say you can ask the user to enter a number referencing a file from the list (should be ok as long as there are not to many files in the folder)

something like this:

```
        DirectoryInfo parentDir = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Deployment/Test_Folder");

        int i = 1;
        foreach (FileInfo f in parentDir.GetFiles())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}. {f.Name}");
            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Please provide the number of the file your want to select (1-{i}):");

        int id = -1;
        if(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out id))
        {
            FileInfo f = parentDir.GetFiles()[id - 1];
            //Do something
        }
```

Comment: If it is possible for the list of files in the directory (shared folder for example or user creating/deleting files in directory) between display & user response - then the wrong file could be selected. It would be better to create a list in memory, display that list & get filename from that list.

Comment: true it's not a foolproof example, it also doesn't check if the int is in range, properly handle non-numeric input etc. but i'd say it gets the point across

Comment: Thanks !! That is what i search ! 


so one Question i have a path like :

public static string DB_restore_path = (WoringPath + @"\Backup\restore\mysqldump.txt");

Now i want to delete the "mysqldump.txt and put the file what i select in your Code must i say 

public static string DB_restore_path = (WoringPath + @"\Backup\restore\ f ????  ");

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

Call with SelectFile(path)
and it will display the files so the user can select with the up and down keys

```
public static string SelectFile(string path)
        {
            bool FileSelect = false;
            int FileChoice = 0;
            List<string> Files = new List<string>();

            foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("."))
            {
                Files.Add(file);
            }
            if (Files.Count > 0)
            {
                FileSelect = true;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
            while (FileSelect)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Select a file");
                for (int i = 0; i < Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == FileChoice)
                    {
                        Console.Write("[*]");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("[ ]");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(Files[i]);
                }
                var key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {
                    FileChoice -= 1;
                    if (FileChoice == -1)
                    {
                        FileChoice = Files.Count - 1;
                    }
                }
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                {
                    FileChoice += 1;
                    if (FileChoice == Files.Count)
                    {
                        FileChoice = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    FileSelect = false;
                }
            }
            return Files[FileChoice];
        }
```